# Recover deleted video in Google Photos app

Tags: data-recovery, google-photos

In Google Photos I deleted permanently a video (before it was backed-up). Is there any way that I can recover it? It's very important to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can only recover videos and photos which aren't permanently deleted. 
But if you have mistakenly permanently deleted the video you can contact Google Drive Support regarding this issue. They might help you with this. 
But I believe it will be more difficult to recover since Google has removed the Google Drive Support for Google Photos.

[Link to Google Drive Support](https://support.google.com/drive/gethelp?authuser=0)